# I do not undestand, why in my project on folder "monto" is in another branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, branch

I do not undestand, why in my gitHub "Monto Project 2019" the folder "monto" is not active? How i will fix that?
[image: Intellij-idea ranch view]

[image: GitHub view]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not active", but the github image snapshot is showing that `monto` is a submodule (or more precisely, a gitlink).

Comment: "monto" folder is not possible to open, because it is empty in github, and not empty in my Project. I can't understand why, other folder possible to open.

Comment: A submodule is another (separate) Git repository. The gitlink entry in the commit tells the superproject Git which commit to check out in the submodule Git. But the submodule Git is another Git repository: if GitHub can't *find* that repository, or cannot access it, it will not be able to show any of it to you. However, *your* computer may have access to it (via ssh key for instance) that GitHub lacks. Or, perhaps GitHub can access the second repository itself, but not the commit, as the commit may not have been pushed yet.

Comment: picture cracks, any word backup?

Answer (score 0):

It is a nested Git repository, recorded as a gitlink.

That means, in your local clone, you have a `.git/` subfolder in the `monto/` directory.

When doing a `git add .` from the root of your main repo, you have recorded `monto` as a gitlink (SHA1 of the tree of the `monto` nested Git repository)

Adding `monto` as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) would be preferable, to not only record the SHA1 of the repo, but *also* its origin URL.